# How to use case expression for tuple in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, switch-statement, tuples

I have a problem when using case expression in Haskell.

```
filterSth::[a]->(b,c)->[a]
filterSth (x:xs) (b, c) =
    case (b,c) of
        (1,0) -> ...
        (1,2) -> ...
        ...
```

can I do something like above ?

Comment: #Haskell at freenode is also a good source of asking small doubts.

Comment: you also don't have to capture the pair explicitly: `filterSth (x:xs) pair = case pair of (1,0) -> ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like the above except that `b` and `c` need to have a numeric type if you want to pattern match them against numeric constants.

Comment: @Z.pyyyy You can't add typeclass constraints in the middle of a type signature. The correct syntax would be `Num (b,c) => [a] -> (b,c) -> [a]`. One way to find out the correct type signature for a function would be to simply not write a type signature and let ghci you the inferred type.

Comment: yeah...as soon as I posted the comment, I realized that...maybe because I am working on my homework which is supposed to due soon and it is late...my brain is in a chaos...thanks for your help~

Comment: @sepp2k: don't you mean `(Num b, Num c) => [a] -> (b,c) -> [a]`?